# WMI Unexpected COM Error -2147352567 when calling recursive function

Tags: python, wmi, scheduler

I am fairly new to python and as part of a program I am creating I am trying to use WMI to get a listing of all processes running and their current processor utilization. I'm also using threading event scheduler to call this every 30 seconds.

```
import wmi
from threading import Timer
import time

c = wmi.WMI()
time_to_sleep  = 30

def get_process_info():
    process_info = {}    
    try:
        for process in c.Win32_Process ():
                id = process.ProcessID
                for p in c.Win32_PerfRawData_PerfProc_Process (IDProcess=id):
                    n1, d1 = long (p.PercentProcessorTime), long (p.Timestamp_Sys100NS)
                    n0, d0 = process_info.get (id, (0, 0))
                    try:
                        percent_processor_time = (float (n1 - n0) / float (d1 - d0)) *100.0
                    except ZeroDivisionError:
                        percent_processor_time = 0.0
                    process_info[id] = (n1, d1)
                    print id, process.Caption, str(percent_processor_time)
    finally: 
        Timer(time_to_sleep, get_process_info, ()).start()
        time.sleep(time_to_sleep) #Sleep while it loops

get_process_info()
```

The first time it runs, it executes fine, but the second time it goes to run it throws an error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 551, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 755, in run
    self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\workspace\WorkflowTesting\Workflow\Workflow.py", line 32, in get_process_info
    for process in c.Win32_Process ():
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 817, in query
    return self._namespace.query (wql, self, fields)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 1009, in query
    return [ _wmi_object (obj, instance_of, fields) for obj in self._raw_query(wql) ]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 1003, in _raw_query
    handle_com_error ()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 241, in handle_com_error
    raise klass (com_error=err)
x_wmi: <x_wmi: Unexpected COM Error (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'SWbemServicesEx', None, None, 0, -2147221008), None)>
```

Comment: If you move to a single thread and just use the sleep function instead it seems to prevent this from erring. Not sure if this causes an issue though somewhere else, or is good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems better to use the following method without threading:

```
import wmi
import time

time_to_sleep  = 30

c = wmi.WMI()
process_info = {}    

while True:
    for process in c.Win32_Process ():
            id = process.ProcessID
            for p in c.Win32_PerfRawData_PerfProc_Process (IDProcess=id):
                n1, d1 = long (p.PercentProcessorTime), long (p.Timestamp_Sys100NS)
                n0, d0 = process_info.get (id, (0, 0))
                try:
                    percent_processor_time = (float (n1 - n0) / float (d1 - d0)) *100.0
                except ZeroDivisionError:
                    percent_processor_time = 0.0
                process_info[id] = (n1, d1)
                print id, process.Caption, str(percent_processor_time)
    time.sleep(time_to_sleep)
```

I am not sure if the sleep time has other implications but for now it seems to work well. I would suspect If I need to complete other actions maybe execute this on a separate thread to those?